# roscore command not found

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I installed properly ROS Hydro, and I've been using it for quite a while.
However, after coming to office the next day. I get the following error

`zsh: command not found: roscore`

This is weird because I am sourcing setup files for both ROS installation and catkin/rosbuild workspaces.
Rosbuild is overlayed with catkin/devel.
Also rosdep is working, and I have all enviromental variables except ROS_ROOT after launching new terminal.
Thought exporting manually ROS_ROOT doesnt help, and when I source manually /opt/ros/hydro/setup.zsh and after rosbuild/setup.zsh or catkin/devel/setup.zsh, I lose all again.

I tried reinstalling ROS, but that didn't fix the problem.

Anyway had a similar problem?, because this sounds really weird to me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190470/roscore-command-not-found/) by [asiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/18762/asiron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-08-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) on 2014-08-18**:
Are you sure you did setup [ROS Environment](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like your workspaces aren't nested properly for some reason. You may want to remove the build and devel folders in your catkin workspace, source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash, and then rebuild it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lalten](https://answers.ros.org/users/25550/lalten/) on 2018-05-30**:
I just upgraded from zesty/lunar to bionic/melodic, and removing ~/catkin_ws/devel worked for me

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`command not found` can mean that the binary in question could not be found, but it can also indicate that the interpreter for that binary was missing.

`which roscore` should tell you if the roscore binary can be found or not. If it isn't found for some reason, you should check that the `ros-hydro-roslaunch` package is installed. If it does exist, you should make sure that it actually exists and isn't a broken symlink or something.

`roscore` uses `/usr/bin/python` as the interpreter, so you should also check that you have a python interpreter installed.

**UPDATE**

On my system, roscore is located in `/opt/ros/hydro/bin/roscore`. If that file doesn't exist, there's something wrong with your installation, and you should reinstall roslaunch with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall rod-hydro-roslaunch`. If it does exist, you should make sure that `/opt/ros/hydro/bin` is in your PATH.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/18762/asiron/) on 2014-08-18**:
Thanks for fast response,

`which roscore` cannot find roscore, and ros-hydro-roslaunch is installed and up to date, also I have working python at /usr/bin/python.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve a similar problem by sourcing the main ros setup.bash file

```
source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
```

and then recompiling in my catkin workspace.

```
~/catkin_sw$ catkin_make
```

It seems that my workspace setup.bash was corrupted somehow.

---

Originally posted by [dmagree](https://answers.ros.org/users/23420/dmagree/) with karma: 91 on 2015-07-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marijn](https://answers.ros.org/users/23671/marijn/) on 2015-08-25**:
This solved the problem for me.

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-01**:
But to me, I have to run this every time I restart my computer. Can this be sovled permanently?

**Comment by [Marijn](https://answers.ros.org/users/23671/marijn/) on 2017-02-02**:
I don't know it if might be of any help but this happened to me because I use QtCreator as IDE and tried to compile my workspace with QtCreator which I didn't start from a terminal (although the tutorial clearly said you should :)). Maybe compiling with a bad environment breaks the workspace somehow

**Comment by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on 2017-11-22**:
This solved the problem in ROS KINETIC on a JETSON TX2.

Thank you.

**Comment by [Void](https://answers.ros.org/users/28605/void/) on 2018-05-03**:
this worked for me; but I also had to source .bashrc after deleting build and devel

**Comment by [kumar_fc](https://answers.ros.org/users/39024/kumar_fc/) on 2019-09-07**:
Worked for me on Jetson Nano. Instead of jade use melodic. Thanks for sharing!